# Delivering mail for some users to external SMTP while the domain is local on Postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, centos7

I want to send mail to an outside Office 365 account with the same domain I have for local accounts.

When I try to send mail to this address outside, Postfix rejects it with error "Account not available".
So, I want Postfix to send mail to outside account for same domain, if that account is not present locally.

For example I have two email address `abc@example.com` and `xyz@example.com`.

- `abc@example.com` is present in local server
- `xyz@example.com` is an account on Office 365 external mailserver.

Now, I want to send mail to `xyz@example.com` from Postfix from any local account. The domain `example.com` is added to `relay_domains` also, but Postfix still rejects mail with error "recipient not present".

Comment: Could you give a more detailed explanation? Or maybe illustrate what you want with a couple of examples (e.g. I have a local account bob with an email address of bob@mydomain, and I want to send mail to alice@herdomain).

Answer (score 2):

As you already have `example.com` as a local domain configured in either `mydestination` or `virtual_alias_domains` you can't achieve this by also adding it to `relay_domains`.

Instead, you should add a [transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) map that can override delivery rules defined by the default `transport:nexthop` used by `mydestination`, `virtual_alias_domains` etc.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The   optional  [transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)  table  specifies  a  mapping  from  email
>   addresses to message delivery  transports  and  next-hop  destinations.
>   Message  delivery  transports  such as local or smtp are defined in the
>   `master.cf` file, and next-hop destinations are typically hosts or domain
>   names. The table is searched by the [trivial-rewrite(8)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Domains-FAQ-1272bad0-4bd4-4796-8005-67d6fb3afc5a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_howdoichangethedefaultdomaininoffice365) daemon.
>
> This  mapping overrides the default `transport:nexthop` selection that is
>   built into Postfix.

Add [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) to your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

And then add to `/etc/postfix/transport`:

```
xyz@example.com    smtp:example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
@example.com       :
*                  :
```

(Remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` as you are using `hash`, Berkeley DB [lookup table](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types).)

This will use default transport rules for all `@example.com` and anything else (`*`) leaving other delivery configuration as is, but forward all email to `xyz@example.com` to Office 365 via SMTP: the default pattern for [Office 365 MX record](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595791(v=exchg.150).aspx) for companies is `<domain>.mail.protection.outlook.com.`

---

Using `transport_maps` is a global solution that will work with any external SMTP server. In a specific scenario, where a) the external account is on Office 365 and b) domain is configured on Postfix `virtual_alias_domains` it could also be possible to add a virtual alias redirecting all mail to Office 365 user's [initial domain](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Domains-FAQ-1272bad0-4bd4-4796-8005-67d6fb3afc5a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_howdoichangethedefaultdomaininoffice365) (tenant) address, `xyz@example.com  xyz@contoso.onmicrosoft.com`.

Comment: I reformatted your question a little to increase readability and added another Office 365 specific solution (while I'd still prefer `transport_maps`). I'm glad this worked for you! Could you accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but for Google Suite/Workspace the URL is `aspmx.l.google.com`, which allows unrestricted/unauthed transport.

See: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-the-restricted-gmail-smtp-server